# How do I have random color variations for grass?

Tags: particles

[image: Reference]

im trying to recreate this grass. i want to have spots with an orange hue, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One technique we use in game-dev is something like this:

Find yourself a grass texture, something with a decent amount of color variation, but it's not extremely important.

[image]

Then in photoshop down-rez the image quite significantly. Like 32x32 pixels is fine.

[image]

Then in the material for your grass set up something like this, with the low-rez ground texture blended with the base color of your grass. Use world-space coordinates for the texture.

[image]

This will give you a result like [this](https://imgur.com/a/m5OkUVn).

You can obviously go to town with different options, this is just a quick rundown of a simple technique.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Render` settings of the particles you can set `Render as` to `Collection`. Put the green grass and orange flowers into the selected Collection. Tick `Use Count` in `Render` section and add some count values to specify how much grass and flowers you want.